# Как указать путь к файлу с использованием %USERNAME%?

Tags: c#

При создании файла или при его чтении я хочу указать путь таким образом, чтобы не приходилось вводить имя пользователя. Как это делается в windows:
C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Documents\users.xml

Но программа не понимает что такое %USERNAME%. Как решить эту проблему? Я хочу, чтобы программа запускалась на других компьютерах и хранила файл конкретно в данной папке

Comment: А зачем навтыкали тегов разных языков? На каком всё-таки пишите программу? [Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System));](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/14tx8hby(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: [ExpandEnvironmentStrings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724265(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: И аналог на .NET [`Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.environment.expandenvironmentvariables?view=netframework-4.7.1).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

На C# это делается так.

```
// получить правильный путь к документам текущего пользователя
var docFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(
        Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments,
        Environment.SpecialFolderOption.Create);
// добавить имя файла с учётом системно-зависимого разделителя
var path = Path.Combine(docFolder, "users.xml");
```

Если надо в общем случае раскрыть переменные окружения, используйте `Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables`. Но не забывайте, что домашний каталог текущего пользователя может храниться вовсе не в `C:\Users\`.

Answer (score 0):

Переменная среды, хранящая путь к профилю текущего пользователя называется `USERPROFILE`, поэтому вам нужен путь: `%USERPROFILE%\Documents\users.xml`

На википедии есть перечень некоторых переменных среды: [Переменная среды Windows](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%8B_Windows)